# Javascript Regex problem

Tags: javascript, regex, dom, replace

I have `<li>` elements in my document such as:

```
<li id="123" onMouseOver="foo();">Lorem Ipsum ...
```

I would like to remove the attributes and get the string `<li>Lorem Ipsum ...`. In order to do that, I use the `replace()` method:

```
foo = document.getElementById('bar');
alert(foo.innerHTML.replace('<li(.*)', '<li>'));
```

But it won't match and returns the exact same string. `<li\(.*\)` was no good either. I tried the regex [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) and it worked. Any suggestions? Would DOM solve this instead of Regex?

---

**EDIT:** Turns out I used the replace method wrong, instead of a pattern I should have provided a `Regexp` object. Thanks to Gobi's answer I corrected my pattern too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `<li[^>]*>` or `<li.*?>`  instead.

However, using html parser instead of regex is always advised.